# Rails Active storage "identify -format %[orientation]" issue on .heic format while updating the metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails(5.2) Active Storage for saving attachments directly in S3.

While uploading the attachment using direct uploads, Blob will be created first and the attachments will be created in Active storage. Then background job will be enqueued for saving the metadata using analyze_blob method.

I am facing the below issue in background job while updating the metadata for .heic image formats in ActiveStorage::Blob table

> MiniMagick::Error: `identify -format %[orientation] /tmp/ActiveStorage20201125-18095-1ccc7me.heic[0]` failed with error:
> identify: no decode delegate for this image format `HEIC' @
> error/constitute.c/ReadImage/564.

Can somebody help on this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

HEIC is a newer format, I would guess that the version of minimagick or imagemagick you're using isn't aware of that format.  You might have luck upgrading to a newer version of imagemagick on the system and/or a newer version of the minimagick gem.